# How to prepare KML file for Android Emulator Control?

Tags: android, debugging, kml

I am trying to test my application with location information.
You know the Emulator Control has an ability to load from KML file. (Eclipse -> DDMS -> Emulator Control -> Location Controls -> KML -> Load KML...)
I've prepared KML file using Google earth application with its "Add path". Then saved it by .kml extension and load it on the Eclipse. Eclipse didn't load this KML file.

How to prepare KML file for Android Emulator Control?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found solution : 
KML format is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.x">
<Placemark>
    <name>1</name>
        <Point><coordinates>-109.0450005395891,33.39487928579279,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Comment: You made my day. Tks

Comment: Doesnt work with multiple coordinates

Answer (score 2):

The KML format that's accepted by ADT (0.8.x) differs from the Google Earth (or even Google Tracks) format.

Convert the original KML file at http://ge2adt.appspot.com/, use your Google  account to login.

You can now try to open the file in the emulator control. I still couldn't open the KML file in the emulator. Open the KML file and remove the 'Document' element, don't delete the 'Placemark' elements. Also check if there multiple KML definitions ('kml' element). I had two definitions with only one placemark, and one correct definition with multiple placemarks. Delete the definitions with only one placemark.

Comment: Link not working anymore

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this, and found actually the only thing you need to change to get the ADT to accept your KML file is to change the namespace to http://earth.google.com/kml/2.x.

You'd think someone at Google would have sorted this out by now...

Answer (score 2):

The KML file must be a 3D file - some GIS tools (e.g. [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org)) don't put the Z value in the output if it is not present in your input data. A simple search and replace to add ,0 before each closing `</coordinate>` tag will solve this problem.