# How to simulate a route (.gpx or .kml), on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, google-earth, gpx

I made a route using Google Earth. Now, i want to import it to my mobile phone. I would like to simulate the route (using a **fake gps**).

I mean, to deceive/simulate to my phone that he is in one place (doing the route), while i am at home, for example.

Does Google Maps affort this? Or there is an app to do it?

In the other hand, i tried with My tracks (although it can not simulate the gps), but when i am going to run it, it goes to the Google Earth's app, and the route doesn't work.

Any thought?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using http://gpx2kml.com/ if you want to convert the kml file to gpx. It's a free online converter and it works both ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Earth to get the kml file and you can use it in Eclipse using ADT. You can load a kml file but actually it uses a different format. See here: [prepare kml file for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109096/how-to-prepare-kml-file-for-android-emulator-control)

Comment: Ok, it's true. But i need to simulate it on the phone (for some reasons). Thank you anyway. Another idea?